# Uma edição deve remover partes irrelevantes a posteriori?

Tags: debate, perguntas, edição

As primeiras revisões [dessa pergunta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/14739/215) não davam informação suficiente para respondê-la. O autor achava que havia postado todo o código relevante, mas era insuficiente. Depois disso ela foi editada, e mais código foi mostrado, permitindo identificar o problema. Entretanto, há código demais - 3 classes citadas não têm relação alguma com a pergunta (que eu tenha visto).

Devo editar a pergunta de modo a remover esse código extra? Sendo que eu só soube o que era relevante e o que não era ***a posteriori*** - já que ainda que tivesse um palpite de qual era o erro, não podia ter certeza antes de ver o código. Mas e se houver algum problema adicional no restante do código que eu não tenha visto? (relevante à pergunta, é claro) Seria o caso então de remover, mas só após o autor confirmar que a resposta está correta? Ou é melhor deixar como está?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Seria o caso então de remover, mas só após o autor confirmar que a resposta está correta?

Eu acredito que sim. É bom esperar a confirmação do autor em relação à(s) resposta(s), mas tendo essa confirmação acho positivo remover código irrelevante. Isso deve aumentar um pouco as chances de que a pergunta se torne relevante para outras pessoas. Como está hoje, só funciona para o próprio autor.